# Set a window as destop background (Windows)

Tags: windows, window, desktop

is there any way to place a window behind the desktop icons or as the backgroud of the desktop?

For example I have a window and I want it to always in the back and below the destop icons.

Comment: Technically, I think the answer is yes.  But it may take a lot of hard work programming, or maybe a software program that someone else created.  The key word you are missing in your question is "Wallpaper". The odds are, if you find something that does what you want, it will likely have the word wallpaper in it.  For example, Wallpaper Engine (Not saying this product will do what you want, I actually have no knowledge of it): https://www.wallpaperengine.io/en

Answer (score 0):

No. Background is background, and is controlled by Windows itself, mostly through theme engine. You can put at best a slideshow - changing wallpaper roughly through API is not so smooth and often produces a flash, while slideshow use transition effects.

It ***was*** possible to display web pages in older Windows versions (it was named "[Active Desktop](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000593.htm)"), but it's long dead now because of obvious security reasons.

Otherwise, everything you can create with an application will be **ABOVE** desktop icons. By design.

You can anyway use some programs that can somewhat perform suitable behavior:

- [SysInternals BgInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/bginfo): Allow to display various informations as an overlay to current wallpaper. Can display various system informations. Can also save you from creating some purely static display components for next tool.
- [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/): Allow to heavily customize your desktop with skins and "widgets" - they are still above icons, so see next one.
- [Desktop Restore](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm): Allow to save/restore icons' positions for multiple configurations / resolutions. Can allow you to let Rainmeters' components in "blank" zones, free of icons.